# How to run specific tests from Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, robotium, gerrit

I'm using Robotium to test an Android application. Tests are triggered automatically when a Gerrit change is merged.

Is there a way to trigger only specific tests (maybe using annotations) when a specific class from the main project (the one that is tested) is changed?

This will be useful because running all the tests takes a lot of time and I would like to run only the tests related to the changed code part.

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger jobs by adding a File path filter to gerrit trigger. or in the latest version you can trigger jobs with TOPIC name as well. See details in [Trigger Configuration section](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger).

Comment: But this only solves half of the problem. It triggers all tests when a specific class is modified. I want to run only specific tests for that change. For example if I change class A I want to run test X, and if I change class B I want to run test Y.

Comment: Assuming your classes placed in separate files, so if the file of Calss A changed, then all the jobs will start by gerrit trigger where the file path filter defines file of Class A. And jobs for Class B not, since the filter is different there.